# A property of dot product?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let's consider a separable Hilbert space $(H, \langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle_H)$ with a orthonormal basis $(h_j)$ and let $x \in H.$ Then, what is the value

$$
  \sum_{i,j=1}^\infty\;\langle x, h_i\rangle_H\langle x, h_j\rangle_H \quad?
$$

Comment: For all sequences $z_j$ you have (modulo convergence issues) $\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^\infty z_iz_j = \left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty z_j\right)^2$. In your situation however, the series $\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty \langle x,h_j\rangle$ need not converge.

Comment: You are right. According Parseval's relation $||x||^2_H = \sum_{i=1}^\infty\;\langle x, h_i\rangle^2_H,$ but $\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty \langle x,h_j\rangle_H$ doesn't have to converge.